# How to change directory then run command batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How would you change the directory in a batch file then run the command in the new directory? I have got the batch file to change the directory, but will not run the command. It is not an exe, it is a file with -options. So basically I need to change the directory, then run a command that is saved in a string.

Comment: post the batch file you have written.

Comment: What is the command you are unable to run after changing directory? Better post the batch file as said by basiljames.

Answer (score 20):

Try using

```
pushd yourdir
filetorun -options
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Worked perfectly.
Thanks,

Dan

Comment: No worries, if this answered your question you should click on the tick to mark this as accepted.

Comment: Normally preferable to "cd", since one can use popd to restore the original directory.

Comment: Why is pushd preferred over cd ?

Answer (score 2):

I have given a sample code below to change the directory and run a command after that.

```
cd C:\    #Will change the directory to C:
ipconfig  #Will return IP address details(any command can be used here)
pause     #Will prevent command prompt from closing and waits for a keypress
```

Save this as a batch file **filename.bat** and you will get desired output. But make sure that the command entered is correct.

Comment: also, if you need to change **drive** as well as directory, use `CD /D`, as just CD will change the directory for that drive, but not change to that drive

Answer (score 1):

`"cd"` stands for `"ChangeDirectory"`. With `"cd"` command you can change the directory.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)

Cheers